# java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Tags: java, multithreading

When i use cycle sentence to run two Threads it shows me that problem:java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
but i figure it out use two methods:\
first if i dont run the application just debug it and use breakpoint it would be ok . 
second based on my demo just has two threads so i could copy this part of code "

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int data = new Random().nextInt();
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                                + " has put data:" + data);
                        threadDataMap.put(Thread.currentThread(), data);
                        new A().get();
                        new B().get();
                    }
                }).start();

"
```

for twice it would also be ok .

all my demo code is below:

```
    package 多线程;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class ThreadScopShareData {

    private static int data = 0;
    private static Map<Thread,Integer> threadDataMap=new HashMap<Thread,Integer>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int data = new Random().nextInt();
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                            + " has put data:" + data);
                    threadDataMap.put(Thread.currentThread(), data);
                    new A().get();
                    new B().get();
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    static class A {
        public void get() {
            int data=threadDataMap.get(Thread.currentThread());
            System.out.println("A from " + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    + "get data:" + data);
        }
    }

    static class B {
        public void get() {
            int data=threadDataMap.get(Thread.currentThread());
            System.out.println("B from " + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    + "get data:" + data);
        }
    }
    }
```

and the right result should be like below:
    Thread-1 has put data :-1188249922
    Thread-0 has put data :1024718434
    A from Thread-0 get data :1024718434
    B from Thread-0 get data :1024718434
    A from Thread-1 get data :-1188249922
    B from Thread-1 get data :-1188249922

but the bug is below:Thread-1 has put data :-807205084
   Thread-0 has put data :-976943511
   A from Thread-0 get data :-976943511

```
   Exception in thread "Thread-1" B from Thread-0 get data :-976943511
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at 多线程.ThreadScopeShareData$A.get(ThreadScopeShareData.java:33)
    at 多线程.ThreadScopeShareData$1.run(ThreadScopeShareData.java:22)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

As far as i know the Thread-1 would totally change and kill the thread-0 so it would appear a nullPointerException . but i am not sure.

Comment: Not clean in which cases you are not getting the expected result

Comment: i meant :if i run this demo it would except a NullPointerException . but i based on my current code , i have two solutions .First is use "debug" command and put some breakpoint in it rather than "run" command . second, if i copy the thread part code for twice rather than use cycle sentence. it would be ok. but i dont know why the Thread was messed up .

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `threadDataMap` in multiple threads use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of `HashMap`.

Comment: thank u very much .and u r right if i use ConcurrentHashMap it would be ok, but could u tell me why it would be messed up if i use just HashMap .

Comment: The cause is in concurrent changing of HashMap internal state.

Comment: Most likely it is the result of concurrent initiation: when thread-1 and thread-0 at same time call put() on empty map, each of them start to create it's own hash-table and since Thread-0 was second to finish this action, it overwritten already created hash-table by Thread-1. So when you try to get data by key 'Thread-1' it returns null.

Comment: i understand now the possible reason. but i am confused with the sequence during  i debug the code below,the order is first i =0 then  create a new Thread instance , then go to  start() method, after that i= 1 create another new Thread instance then go to start method . after both finished , it goes to the run() method.  :
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                }
            }).start();}

Comment: i think the sequence maybe should be like this : after i=0 , it create a new Thread instance then , just go to start() and go to run() method. after this , i=1 , it create another new Thread instance then go to its start() method and go to this run() method. and when i copy this code:new Thread(new runnable(){@override public void run(){}}).start();  twice , the sequence is like what  i described . and maybe that is the reason. I really want to know why if i use "for" cycle the run order would be like that .

Comment: Sequence here is NOT constant and it could be different on each run, it depends on your OS thread scheduler. You can run your program 100 times and it will crash on this point, but at 101 run it could finished OK. You can give your program to your friend and on his machine it could be OK the most time. The cause of problem is not in some concrete sequence, the problem is that we can't have any expectations about this sequence, it's not specified and could be random.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of your System Preferences language setting in **Processing**, change it from Chinese to English.